# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'write_dot' for networkx library

Tags: python, graph, networkx, dot

I am using `networkx` library for reading and writing `dot` graphs. According to the [documentation here](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/development/reference/generated/networkx.drawing.nx_agraph.write_dot.html), `write_dot()` method should be accessible, however when I try,

```
>>> import networkx
>>> networkx.write_dot(graph,fileName)
```

I get the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'write_dot'
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try:

```
from networkx.drawing.nx_agraph import write_dot
```

or

```
 from networkx.drawing.nx_pydot import write_dot
```

Comment: For later versions like for version 2 following might work - 
networkx.nx_pydot.write_dot(graph,fileName)