# converting network graph to graphviz

Tags: python, networkx, graphviz, pydot

I am having trouble visualizing a multidirectional graph with parallel edges in networkx so I have resorted to using pydot, but I am having two issues

1) I  cant seem to understand why the node positions are not being fixed I would like to plot them at the x and y specified coordinates
2) How do I set the size of the figure being plotted the plt.figure command does not really work
3) How do I add edge labels (if I had them)

many thanks

```
import networkx as nx  
from io import StringIO
from io import BytesIO

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
import networkx as nx


graph= nx.MultiGraph()                                                                                    

#add 4 nodes in the vertexs of a square. X and Y are the coordinates                                      
graph.add_node(1,x=100,y=100)                                                                             
graph.add_node(2,x=100,y=200)                                                                             
graph.add_node(3,x=200,y=100)                                                                             
graph.add_node(4,x=200,y=200)                                                                             
graph.add_edge(1,2)                                                                                       
graph.add_edge(2,1)   
graph.add_edge(3,1)
graph.add_edge(3,4)                                                                                       
graph.add_edge(4,1)                                                                                       
                                                                                                         # assign positions                                                                                        
for n in graph:                                                                                           
    graph.node[n]['pos'] = '"%d,%d"'%(graph.node[n]['x'], graph.node[n]['y'])                             
p = nx.drawing.nx_pydot.to_pydot(graph)                                                                                    

# render pydot by calling dot, no file saved to disk
png_str = p.create_png(prog='C:\\Anaconda3\\Library\\bin\\graphviz\\dot.exe')

# treat the dot output string as an image file
sio = BytesIO()
sio.write(png_str)
sio.seek(0)
img = mpimg.imread(sio)





plt.figure(figsize = (10,10))
imgplot = plt.imshow(img)
```

Answer (score 4):

**TLDR** (a) use neato, not dot to draw (b) pos attrs should be of the form "100,200!" in the dot file. Don't double-quote it, and add an ! mark.

Firstly, not all of the graphviz tools support positions. See [docs](https://www.graphviz.org/doc/info/attrs.html#d:pos):

> In neato and fdp, pos can be used to set the initial position of a node

Secondly, once you are using a tool that reads the `pos` attribute, you'll see some errors in the output.  To understand problems with an external tool, it makes more sense to test it in isolation, so let's do that to file:

```
nx.drawing.write_dot(graph, "test.dot")
```

And then run `neato`:

```
> neato -Tpng test.dot >test1.png 
Error: node 1, position "100,100", expected two doubles
Error: node 2, position "100,200", expected two doubles
Error: node 3, position "200,100", expected two doubles
Error: node 4, position "200,200", expected two doubles
```

You'll now see that the format isn't right.  And so neato proceeds to layout the graph as if `pos` wasn't specified.

[image: automatic layout, ignoring pos attr]

```
for n in graph:
    graph.node[n]['pos'] = "{},{}!".format(
        graph.node[n]['x'], graph.node[n]['y'])
```

Now try again:

```
nx.drawing.write_dot(graph, "test_fix.dot")

# note: the -n flag causes neato to use points rather than inches. 
# see docs, and/or experiment with -s setting as well
> neato -n -Tpng test_fix.dot >test2.png
```

And positions are now respected:

[image: format of pos argument correct]

### Edge labels and image size

The dot manual and this site both have info on how to draw edge labels (e.g. [How to add edge labels in Graphviz?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1806870/how-to-add-edge-labels-in-graphviz) or [Graphviz: Place edge label on the other side (II)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18515529/graphviz-place-edge-label-on-the-other-side-ii)), and obviously you need to add some property to your graph (see "associate data to edges using keywords": https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/generated/networkx.DiGraph.add_edge.html )

It isn't clear what you mean by "plt.figure command does not really work" but this is quite far from the networkx issues here so I think it would be better to post a new question that isolates the problem and explains it fully.

Comment: hi thanks for this and apologies for more noob questions

Comment: @qfd no probs.  If the answer helped resolve your problem, please consider accepting it ([click the green tick at the top left of the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/208898))!

Comment: Good answer, thanks. I was getting the "expected two doubles" complaint trying to build the pos assignment dynamically, until I built the string value for it ahead of time. For each node, from a "vals" position array, I built a pos string, and then assigned it:
rows=["A","B","C","D","E"]
for r in range(len(rows)):
  x=str(vals[r][7]+0.0)
  y=str(vals[r][8]+0.0)+"!"
  posstr=x+","+y
  network.node(rows[r],pos=posstr)

Comment: Whoa, thanks!! For me both the format with and without the ! are working, however, if I **don't** put it, then the positions of the nodes are exactly equal to the ones I specify, while if I **do** put it, then the positions are close, but not exactly the ones I specified. I am wondering if it means that they are taken as "initial" positions, and then relaxed to something close to them. Do you know why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

```
digraph G {
    graph [bb="0,0,270,396",
        sep="+6",
        splines=true
    ];
    node [label="\N",
        nodesep=.4,
        pin=true,
        style=invis
    ];
    edge [style=invis];
    {
        graph [rank=same];
        node [style=solid];
        1   [height=0.5,
            pos="27,378",
            width=0.75];
    }
    {
        graph [rank=same];
        node [style=solid];
        2   [height=0.5,
            pos="27,306",
            width=0.75];
        3   [height=0.5,
            pos="99,306",
            width=0.75];
        5   [height=0.5,
            pos="243,306",
            width=0.75];
    }
    {
        graph [rank=same];
        node [style=solid];
        c1  [height=0.5,
            pos="27,234",
            style=invis,
            width=0.75];
        6   [height=0.5,
            pos="99,234",
            width=0.75];
    }

    1 -> 2  [pos="e,27,324.1 27,359.7 27,351.98 27,342.71 27,334.11"];
    2 -> c1 [pos="e,27,252.1 27,287.7 27,279.98 27,270.71 27,262.11"];

edge[constraint=false style=solid]  

1 -> 2 [label=aaa ]
1 -> 3 [label=abb] 
1 -> 5 [label=abc ]
1 -> 6   [label=aba]
3 -> 6 
}
```

Linux command to run neato - note the "**-s**" option
**F=stylized1Tiny; neato -s -Tpng $F.dot >$F.png;**

[image]